# Unable to import packages in python project using setuptools

Tags: python-2.7, setuptools

When I try to run setup.py using the command:
python setup.py sdist --dist-dir dist

This creates the compressed file under dist folder but when i try to run to code it shows the error that 'No module named slacker found'
Although slacker-0.9.24-py2.7.egg is created in my root folder.
The directory structure is :

```
--quality-sanity-checks
-----setup.py
-----notify
       |---<my python files>




from setuptools import setup
    setup(
        name='quality-sanity',
        version='0.0.1-SNAPSHOT',
        description='Service to alert on quality issues',
        download_url='http://gec-maven-nexus.walmart.com/nexus/content/repositories',
        license='proprietary',
        setup_requires=[
            'requests',
            'slacker'
        ],
        install_requires=[
            'requests',
            'slacker'
        ],
        zip_safe='true'
        #dependency_links=['http://github.com/os/slacker/tarball/master#egg=slacker-0.9.24']
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because *python setup.py sdist --dist-dir dist* will create the file in the zip inside your "dist" folder, and if you'll try to run the python and try to import from the **same** dir path *from slacker import Slacker* won't give you any issue, but if you'll try to import the respective from any other dir path you'll face the error *ImportError: No module named slacker*. It's because the respective import file is present only inside the source folder where you have ran the *python setup.py sdist --dist-dir dist* command.

And, your doubt that why the respective *slacker-0.9.24-py2.7-egg.info* folder is created in your root directory you can refer the answer of following question: [Why does "python setup.py sdist" create unwanted "PROJECT-egg.info" in project root directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3779915/why-does-python-setup-py-sdist-create-unwanted-project-egg-info-in-project-r)