# How to distribute specific files using setuptools?

Tags: python, pip, setuptools

I would to like to distribute a python package using my setup.py, where the user is able to choose which modules will be installed.

In my case, I have the test module, where It's useful in only few cases, so it doesn't make sense distribute that module.

I can exclude the module easily by  `packages=find_packages(exclude=("conans.test*",))`. However, I can't distribute it dynamically.

My idea is, package all files, but only install according the pip command. I would like to install the test module, only when the extra is configured:

```
pip install package[test]
```

Otherwise, it will not install the test module.

When I say test module, it means a folder with all those tests, not the requirements_test.txt file.

Is it possible using setuptools?

Regards!

Comment: [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3779915/why-does-python-setup-py-sdist-create-unwanted-project-egg-info-in-project-r) follow this solution , by jathanism , create a class which do the thing you want and for that taskk create a cli argument in cmdclass

Comment: A package is atomic and can't be reduced any further. Split your project into two dists, `conans` and `conans_tests` (optionally with `conans` being a namespace package). Extras are for reducing only the set of dependencies, not the codebase to install.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to [hoefling](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2650249/hoefling)!

Since it's possible create a dynamic package, the best that I found is run a script after install the package:

https://github.com/uilianries/conan-ldap-authentication/blob/master/setup.py#L40