# How to clean up xxx.egg-info and build folders after building a wheel package using setup.cfg

Tags: python, setuptools, python-wheel

I am following the tutorial [here](https://packaging.python.org/tutorials/packaging-projects/) to package a python project into a wheel package. I am using *setup.cfg* to do the build. I was able to do

```sh
python -m build --wheel
```

to create the wheel package. However, I'd like to automatically clean up the unwanted folders "build/" and "xxx.egg-info" after I get the wheel package in "dist/". I did a lot of search but the only answers I found were for using *setup.py* (e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3779915/why-does-python-setup-py-sdist-create-unwanted-project-egg-info-in-project-r)). I wonder if there's any way to do the cleanup with *setup.cfg* as well?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

AFAIK you can't, build can only be cleaned from a `setup.py` script, and the egg-info dir can not be cleaned up at all. You can, however, point both dirs to temp dir so they are cleaned up on the next reboot. For example, put in your `setup.cfg`:

```
[build]
build-base = /tmp/build

[egg_info]
egg-base = /tmp
```

Or you can call a fake setup script without creating it, with the `clean` subcommand. This will only remove the `build` directory, though:

```
$ python -c "from setuptools import setup; setup()" clean --all
```

Comment: That's a little discouraging to know; hope this functionality can be implemented at some point.

Comment: 2023 and it's still an open, unassigned issue on setuptools' github: https://github.com/pypa/setuptools/issues/1347