# Can't sdist a module with setuptools when setup.cfg is write-protected

Tags: python, setuptools, python-packaging

I'm packaging with a small module named *my_module*; the build is described by a *setup.cfg / setup.py* pair. **Those files are read-only** (as they are monitored by a version controler that mark all files as read-only unless explicitely marked for edit).

The *setup.cfg* file looks like:

```
[metadata]
name = my_module
...

[options]
package_dir =
    = src
packages = find:
python_requires = >=3.6
install_requires =
    ...

[options.packages.find]
where = src
```

And the module tree is the following:

```
my_module_folder/
  setup.cfg
  setup.py
  src/
     my_module/
       __init__.py
       ...
```

sdist-ing it yields the following:

```
$ python3 setup.py sdist
running sdist
running egg_info
writing src/my_module.egg-info/PKG-INFO
writing dependency_links to src/my_module.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
writing requirements to src/my_module.egg-info/requires.txt
writing top-level names to src/my_module.egg-info/top_level.txt
reading manifest file 'src/my_module.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
writing manifest file 'src/my_module.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'

running check

creating my_module-1.0.0
creating my_module-1.0.0/src
...
copying files to my_module-1.0.0...
copying setup.cfg -> my_module-1.0.0                                 # here
copying setup.py -> my_module-1.0.0
copying src/my_module/__init__.py -> my_module-1.0.0/src/my_module
...
Writing my_module-1.0.0/setup.cfg                                    # and there
error: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'my_module-1.0.0/setup.cfg'
```

Note that at some point, *setuptools* will copy the **read-only** *setup.cfg* into the package, then later attempt to overwrite it to add an "[egg_info]" section:

```
[egg_info]
tag_build =
tag_date = 0
```

Of course that can only fails since *setup.cfg* was copied with its read-only attribute...

I *could* harshly alter permissions or file mask prior doing the build, in the *setup.py*, but I am looking for a more elegant solution. Any clue?

Comment: Have you tried looking at the changes the writing of the `setup.cfg` would perform? Or rather do you know for a fact that the sdist command would make undesirable changes to the file?

Comment: @YoshiMbele it added an "[egg_info]" section in setup.cfg with the following:
"tag_build =" and "tag_date = 0". I've updated the question.
I'm not familiar with setuptools, I did not even know that it would embed setup.cfg in the distribution.

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3779915/why-does-python-setup-py-sdist-create-unwanted-project-egg-info-in-project-r) may be related. I am honestly not sure if you should mark both `setup.py` and `setup.cfg` as uneditable by your VCS.